# Отношения один ко многим

Tags: laravel

Помогите указать правильно отношения

Модель Menu_group

Модель Menu

Таблица в базе menus - id | name | group_id

Таблица в базе menu_groups - id | name

Как составить отношения один ко многим в моделях, главная модель Menu_group?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, отношения не работали так как я использовал tinker для проверки, а при изменении надо выходить и заходить заново